# How to fix Error 29 in iphone 4S

Tags: iphone

How can I fix error 29 in iPhone 4s , I am using the Original battery of the iPhone and the phone was working then it became disabled as I tried flashing it it went to the error error 29 (gas Gauge error) any way to skip it and flash it

Comment: Duplicate of [iPhone 4S error in flashing (error 29)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387401/iphone-4s-error-in-flashing-error-29)

Comment: Please don't just post the same question again. if you have detail to add, please edit into your original question.